# Using square of a variable in R Formulas

Tags: r, formula

I'm trying to run a regression including the square of the independent variable.  Other transformations seem to work, but the square isn't recognized.  eg

```
lm(y ~ x + x^2 + sin(x), data=as.data.frame(cbind(x=rnorm(10), y=rnorm(10))))

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x + x^2 + sin(x), data = as.data.frame(cbind(x = rnorm(10), 
   y = rnorm(10))))

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x       sin(x)  
    -0.1594      -0.6171       1.2072
```

The sin is recognized, but the x^2 is not.

Comment: It is recommended to use `poly` for this purpose, or at least `I(x^2)`.

Comment: @Pascal `poly` can give confusing coefficients in it's default configuration, and can be difficult to drop terms from.

Comment: @James Probably. That is why the help page exists.

Comment: @Pascal Except that the help file only mentions they are orthogonal polynomials by default, not that they will give rise to misleading coefficients in a linear model.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to wrap in an `I` to treat the term "as is" rather than interpreting the `^` as a formula operator (see `?formula` for details of this).

```
lm(y ~ x + I(x^2) + sin(x), data=as.data.frame(cbind(x=rnorm(10), y=rnorm(10))))

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x + I(x^2) + sin(x), data = as.data.frame(cbind(x = rnorm(10), 
    y = rnorm(10))))

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x       I(x^2)       sin(x)  
    0.06850      2.82023     -0.03109     -3.84221
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write

```
lm(y ~ x + c(x*x) + sin(x), data=as.data.frame(cbind(x=rnorm(10), y=rnorm(10))))
```